# Why is my HTTPost in android gives me null on JSP page?

Tags: android, jsp, http

I am building an app which tracks the user with latitude and longitude. This latitude and longitude has to be posted to a server.

I build a service so that it gives me the users current location.

This is my code:

MYService.java

```
package com.example.rama.locationtracking;

/**
 * Created by RAMA on 4/10/2016.
 */

public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "SRI";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0;
    private double Longitude,Latitude;
    private static String url ="http://49.206.9.182:8080/ezomart/latlong.jsp";
    private String latitude_str;
    private String longitude_str;


    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        Location mLastLocation;


        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            Longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Latitude = location.getLatitude();
            postToWebServer(Longitude,Latitude);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    private void postToWebServer(double longitude, double latitude)
    {
        latitude_str = String.valueOf(latitude);
        longitude_str = String.valueOf(longitude);

        Log.e(TAG,latitude_str);
        Log.e(TAG, longitude_str);


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://49.206.9.182:8080/ezomart/latlong.jsp");


        //Post Data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", latitude_str));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", longitude_str));


        //Encoding POST data
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //making POST request.
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // write response to log
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
//            Log.d("Http Post Response:", responseBody);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            }
        }).start();
    }


    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();
//        makePostRequestOnNewThread();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

    }
```

JSP Code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
String lat=request.getParameter("userName");        
String longg=request.getParameter("password");
%>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <%=lat%>, <%=longg%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: What is the problem?? Response is Null?? or Request is Null??

Comment: I am getting the response but the request seems to null

Comment: when I log the statement ( Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString()))   I get the following message. D/Http Post Response:: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@a6541408

Comment: I am getting the following result in the logcat.    
 <!DOCTYPE html><html>    <head>        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">        <title>JSP Page</title>    </head>    <body>                <h1>Hello World!</h1>        65.96669666666666, -18.5333    </body></html>. but when i refresh the page it gives me null on the JSP Page

Comment: `Log.d("Http Post Response:", responseBody);`. You commented it. But that gives you the returned html page you posted in the last comment. Perfect! What do you want more? All works!

Comment: What do you mean with: "when i refresh te page" ? Where, how and when are you doing that?

Comment: when I refresh the page (the url i posted should get updated with these values).When I refresh the page on the browser the values are not getting updated it gives me null.

Comment: Are you using the same page in the browser? That page expects that you post a latitude and longitude. Are you posting them in the browser too?  Don't think so. You just want to know the last posted location. For that you first should save the last location on the server. Then make another page that retrieves that. Use that last page in your browser. You should rethink the design of your app. So you want to use an app and a browser? The browser is for 'the people at home?

Comment: The app is used for tracking persons. we need to track people in real time similar like uber.

Comment: Why arent you reacting on the things i said?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110141/discussion-between-srikanth86in-and-greenapps).